# Opening new window with embedded image

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to open a new window that displays a larger version of the clicked embedded image when the image is clicked on the original page. Is this possible?

I have tried something like the following (I don't have the actual code right now but hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do) but the window is opening without the image, just a blank page.

The embedded image data is also just an example. The big image and the small image actually differ in the real case.

```
<a href="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub/
/ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcpp
V0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g77ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNg YPj/gAwXEQA7">
<img onclick="var largeImgSrc=parentNode.href;
window.open(largeImgSrc,"width=400,height=300");
return false;" src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub/
/ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcpp
V0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g77ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7"></img>
</a>
```

So, I'm storing the larger image source at the `href` attribute of the anchor. When the image is clicked, the `onclick` event should be sent and the javascript should be executed opening a new window that contains the image.

Since it's opening the window but not showing anything I'm thinking there is something wrong with using the data source `uri` rather than a link to the actual image.

Comment: it would be more readable if the javascript was in a separate section (instead of in-line with your HTML)  - Are you allowed to do that?

Comment: I would also suggest against putting spaces everywhere around your attributes and their values. The readability for fellow programmers is hurt.

Answer (score 1):

The first quote mark `"` before the word "width" closes the onclick attribute, breaking your function. You can either clean it up or create a function to handle these in a generic fashion.

```
<a href = "data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub/
/ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcpp
V0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g77ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNg YPj/gAwXEQA7">
<img onclick="fruitloop(this)" src = "data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub/
/ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcpp
V0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g77ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7"></img>
</a>
<script>
    function fruitloop(that){
        var largeImgSrc = that.parentNode.href;
        console.log(largeImgSrc)
        window.open(largeImgSrc,"width = 400, height = 300");
        return false;

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Suggestion to OP along with that perfectly good answer: Since the URL is the same in the `href` and in the `src` attributes, perhaps simply doing `var largeImgScr = that.src;` could do the trick too (and prevent copying the dataURI twice and bloat the code).

Comment: The real images are not equivalent - I should have made this clear in my OP, sorry! I'm also failing to see how this really differs from my original post other than the refactoring to make it clearer to read.

Comment: @PaulGothard your original post contains errors - this answer is not 1-for-1 equivalent to your post (see my answer for more details)

Comment: OK, updated with intent. Actually, after a second look, you could just use target on your href :) `<a target="_blank" href = "data:image...`

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have the following:

`onclick="var largeImgSrc=parentNode.href;
window.open(largeImgSrc,".....`

Your double-quotes at the invocation of `window.open(largeImgSrc," <- this one` is closing the one started by `onclick=" <- this one` basically leaving the rest of the `JS` code incomplete.

Your window opens, but the function is malformed and so things fail, fast (you may even be getting console errors because of this - I'd be surprised if you didn't already).

This is the kind of stuff hard to detect when everything is inline like you did in your sample code.

So, for readability, I broke the JS into a separate function added `onclick` to `href` instead of image

**Note:** the code below is sandboxed and it will not open a new window.  You will need to try this on your own page/code

```js
function openImg() {
  var largeImgSrc = "data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub//ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcppV0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g77ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7"

  window.open(largeImgSrc, "title here", "width=400, height=300");
  return false;

}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="openImg()">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub/
/ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcpp
V0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g77ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNg YPj/gAwXEQA7" />
</a>
```